# Tension of a curled chain, connected with understanding the chain fountain

Tags: centripetal-force

I'd like to understand the physics of a chain fountain (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dQJBBklpQQ) and in order to do so, I am reading this paper credited for solving the mystery:
http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/470/2163/20130689

Yet, I have trouble with the first equation, specifically $\frac{T_C}{r}=\frac{ \lambda v^2 }{r}$. Where does it come from? The right part seems like a representation for the centripetal force, but that's everything I am able to decipher.

Comment: The article indeed states that the *centripetal acceleration is then provided by the tension in the chain*, so what is it about that statement/derivation that is confusing to you?

Comment: I can't see it in a mathematical way. I don't know where the $force/radius$ term comes from, I've never seen something like this learning mechanics.

Comment: [The reason of anti gravity of bead chain fountain and the reason of lift ](https://youtu.be/m7uic8nNJ60) Yes, you can choose English subtitles

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70345/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/138270/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about $\frac{\lambda v^2}{r}$, it is the centripetal force per unit length. The $\frac{T_C}{r}$ term is the component of tension force per unit length, acting perpendicular to the chain.

Let's show this. Consider a small, curved segment of the chain with mass per unit length $\lambda$. The curve can be described as subtending an angle $\theta$ of a circle with radius $r$.

The directions of the tensions $T_1$ and $T_2$ (both equal to $T_C$) at the two ends of the chain segment differ by the angle $\theta$. Aligning our axes opposite $T_1$, we have:

$$F_\| = -T_1\cos0 + T_2\cos\theta \approx 0$$
$$F_\perp = -T_1\sin0 + T_2\sin\theta = T_2\sin \theta \approx T_2\theta$$

Where I've used the small angle approximations $\cos\theta \approx 1$, $\sin\theta \approx \theta$. Dividing by the $\text{length} = r\theta$ of the chain segment:

$$ \frac{F_\perp}{\text{length}} = \frac{T_2\theta}{r\theta} = \frac{T_C}{r}$$

And that's it.